# Swift replacement for CGContextAddEllipseInRect

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift, it is apparent that the codes are constantly changing. I am currently completing the youtube tutorial- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvKyeOqMldA, which I found interesting but couldn't move forward after 10 minutes of the tutorial.  I am getting the following error message:
[See details below: "CGContextAddEllipseInRect' has been replaced by instance method 'CGContext.addEllipse(in:)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNh88.png)

Comment: Please place your code and exception in the question body itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please read and try to understand the error message. Sometimes the error messages of Xcode are confusing for beginners but this one is very clear because the compiler shows you the replacement instantly:

> CGContextAddEllipseInRect' has been replaced by instance method 'CGContext.addEllipse(in:)

means that instead of the function

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, imgRect)
```

you have to call `addEllipse(in:)` on the `CGContext` instance:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.addEllipse(in: imgRect)
```

---

Use code completion to see the full signature of the method and how to apply the parameter(s).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works, you just have to change the method names:

```
var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

context?.addEllipse(in: CGRect())

context?.clip()
```